# validate date ('MMMM DD YYYY') format via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Can anyone help me to know javascript regex match
to validate `January-01-2018` date format ('MMMM DD YYYY')  via JavaScript?

I have done for validation for the below date earlier:

```
var date = "2017/01/13";
var regex = /^[0-9]{4}[\/][0-9]{2}[\/][0-9]{2}$/g;
console.log(regex.test(date));    // true
console.log(regex.test("13/01/2017")); //false
console.log(regex.test("2017-01-13")); // false
```

Comment: Why do you want a regular expression for it?

Comment: @putvande To make it work I tried using a regular expression. Do you know any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.prototype.fromString = function(str, ddmmyyyy) {
    var m = str.match(/(\d+)(-|\/)(\d+)(?:-|\/)(?:(\d+)\s+(\d+):(\d+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\.(\d+))?)?/);
    if(m[2] == "/"){
        if(ddmmyyyy === false)
            return new Date(+m[4], +m[1] - 1, +m[3], m[5] ? +m[5] : 0, m[6] ? +m[6] : 0, m[7] ? +m[7] : 0, m[8] ? +m[8] * 100 : 0);
        return new Date(+m[4], +m[3] - 1, +m[1], m[5] ? +m[5] : 0, m[6] ? +m[6] : 0, m[7] ? +m[7] : 0, m[8] ? +m[8] * 100 : 0);
    }
    return new Date(+m[1], +m[3] - 1, +m[4], m[5] ? +m[5] : 0, m[6] ? +m[6] : 0, m[7] ? +m[7] : 0, m[8] ? +m[8] * 100 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

You could let the Date constructor deal with it instead of the regex

```
function isValidDate(date){
    return typeof(date) === 'string' && new Date(date) != "Invalid Date";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this but this didn't work